# Precision Recall calculations in POS tagging

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am trying to find the precision and recall in POS tag.

**Case-1** 
Say the Golden data in this case is

```
Secretariat[NNP] is[VBZ] expected[VBN] to[TO] race[VB] tomorrow[NR]
```

and the Test data is

```
Secretariat[NNP] is[VBZ] expected[VBN] to[TO] race[NN] tomorrow[NR]
```

Here,

```
5 is TruePsotive, 
1 FalsePositive [NN], 
1 FalseNegative [VB]  
Precision = TP/(TP+FP)=5/6 
Recall = TP/(TP+FN)=5/6
```

**Case-2**
In this case, we have total 700 tokens and some of the Tokens are tagged as "UNK" tag by the tagger, which is not present in the Golden data as well as in Training Data.

In the training data, some of the tag was not given, so tester take those unknown tag as "UNK" and then provided the output tagged file.

In the output we have observed that,

```
500 tokens tagged by the tagger correctly, (True Positive)
200 tokens tagged incorrectly (False Positive)
100 tokens tagged as UNK (False negative)
```

So in this case,

```
Precision = 500/700 = 0.714285714 
Recall = 500/600 = 0.833333333
```

Is the calculation correct for the both cases? Please do let me know.